# Defining the area and perimeter of a rectangle in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am a beginner in Objective-C and have been reading a book. I am now stuck on one of the exercises that I have to do at the end of each chapter. This is what I have so far. How do I define the area and perimeter? I'm not asking what the formula for area is (eg... length x width). I am asking how to implement that into the code. I know it is something simple but I just cant figure it out. Thanks in advance!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// insert code here...
@interface Rectangle : NSObject 

-(void) setWidth: (int) w;
-(void) setHeight: (int) h;
-(int) width;
-(int) height;
-(int) area;
-(int) perimeter;

@end

@implementation Rectangle
{
    int width;
    int height;
    int area;
    int perimeter;
}

-(void) setWidth:(int) w {
    width = w;
}

-(void) setHeight:(int) h {
    height = h;
}

-(int) width {
    return width;
}

-(int) height {
    return height;
}

-(int) area {
    return area;
}

-(int) perimeter {
    return perimeter;
}

@end 


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        Rectangle *rec1 = [Rectangle new] ;
        [rec1 setWidth:10];
        [rec1 setHeight:10];
   }
   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perimeter looks like it's being returned here:

```
-(int) perimeter
{
    return perimeter;
}
```

I would get rid of the `perimeter` instance variable and do this instead:

```
-(int) perimeter
{
    return 2 * (width + height);
}
```

Same thing for the area. Get rid of the `area` instance variable and do this:

```
-(int) area
{
    return width * height;
}
```

Comment: How would I then get that to show up in the programming section?

Comment: If you mean inside `int main()`, you would say `rec1.perimeter` and `rec1.area`.

Comment: For correctness' sake, `perimeter` is neither private nor a property.

Comment: How would I syntax that?  I am really sorry if I am sounding stupid, but like I said, I've just started.

Comment: You can use the values however you want, e.g. try `NSLog(@"%@", rec1.perimeter);` to show the value in the console in Xcode.

Comment: @DaltonHinterscher well, you need to call the method. `int per = [someObject perimeter];`

Comment: I just tried the NSLog method and nothing shows up in the console... Is there something I'm not doing?

Comment: Oh, I guess change `NSLog(@"%@"` to `NSLog(@"%i"` since you're trying to print an integer. If that doesn't work, are you getting any warnings?

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much woz! Would there be an easier way instead of the NSLog method such as a -(void) print or would the NSLog way be easiest?

Comment: No problem! `NSLog` is the only way to write to the console that I know of. You could make a wrapper function if you wanted, i.e. `-(void)print:(int)value { NSLog("%i", value); }` and call it like `[self print:rec1.perimeter];`.

Answer (score 0):

You return an expression of the width and the height instead of an instance variable, like this:

```
- (int)area
{
    return width * height;
}

- (int)perimeter
{
    return 2 * (width + height);
}
```

By the way, pay attention to the formatting of your code. Too much vertical whitespace and inconsistent indentation is not good.